# Wordpress: Categories & Menus not saving

Tags: wordpress

I'm somewhat new to WordPress so this may very well be something I'm doing wrong.

No matter what I do I am unable to save categories or custom menus. I go through the motions and it appears to work (I even get the notification that it worked) but when I go back to either the Categories or Menus pages they're not there. Strange thing is I think they're being saved to the DB because if I create a new category it creates an incremental slug (ie: seasonality-7).

If I go to the dashboard it [says I have 8 categories](http://cl.ly/6BAm). But if I go to the categories page it [says there are none](http://cl.ly/6ASo).

Could this have anything to do with themes I'm using? Is there a setting I'm missing?

I really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I've gone through and disabled all plugins and I'm still unable to save cats or menus.

Comment: What Wp version are you using?

Comment: Could this be related to the fact my host is running PHP 5.1 and not 5.2?

Comment: Have you tried it on a local XAMPP server?

Comment: No, not yet. Trying to avoid having to move this around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to ssh into root to edit the my.cnf file to use another directory for tmp. Fixed the issue.